# Listing photos in collection view

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to do a multiple image selection to replace an image picker.

So far the code works and the images are selected correctly but the previews show the original image, even if an image has been edited.

The code i have for getting the photos is:

```
PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
        switch status {
        case .authorized:
            print("Good to proceed")
            let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
            fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
            self.allPhotos = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.reloadImages()
            }
        case .denied, .restricted, .notDetermined:
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }
```

And it is displayed using

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> PhotoLibraryImagesCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoLibraryImagesCell
    let asset = allPhotos?.object(at: indexPath.row)

    cell.imageView.image = nil
    cell.imageView.fetchImage(asset: asset!, contentMode: .aspectFit, targetSize: cell.imageView.frame.size)

    return cell
}
```

How the image looks in photos
[image]

And this is how it appears in my app. Notice in photos the orientation has been changed
[image]

Comment: There's a sample code download at the top of this documentation page, which is what I've used as a base for my implementations in the past. I suggest you take a look, it's quite a bit of logic to get right. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/browsing_and_modifying_photo_albums

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the latest version of the image using the below

```
let manager = PHImageManager.default()
let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
options.version = .current
options.isSynchronous = false
manager.requestImageData(for: asset, options: options) { data, _, _, _ in

    if let data = data {
        if let img = UIImage(data: data) {
            cell.imageView.image = img
        }
    }
}
```